# Create the same JavaScript object with multiple arguments sets

Tags: javascript

I want to initialize an javascript object Person.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.hash = hash(name);
        this.name = name;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + " hashValue: " + this.hash;
    }
}
```

`hash(string)` is an existing function which returns the `hash` value.

When the webpage is loaded I append li's to an ul on the webpage with content from the Person objects. So I need to create the person object's client side every time the webpage is reloaded.

The user can also create a new Persons. When a new person is created a new hashValue must be calculated. But when existing Persons are retrieved from the database there already exist an hashValue. I don't want to calculate the hashValue in this case.

I want to create an Person object with:

```
const pers1 = new Person(name); // user adds new Person

const pers2 = new Person(hash, name); // Person from database
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it's possible

- The function must be called different than `hash` to avoid a logic clash.

**Ask for the passed hash param:**

```
this.hash = hash ? hash : hashthis(name);
```

**Snippet:**

*This is just an example to demonstrate the logic*

```js
function hashthis(str) {
  return `Hash(${str})`;
}
  
class Person {
  constructor(name, hash) {
    this.hash = hash ? hash : hashthis(name);
    this.name = name;
  }   
  
  toString() {
    return this.name + " hashValue: " + this.hash;
  }
}

console.log(new Person('Ele'));
console.log(new Person('Ele', 'dhgf65df6df7'));
```

Or you can initialize your param with a default value using the function `hashthis`.  This initialization will occur only if hash param is undefined/not passed.

```
constructor(name, hash = hashthis(name))
```

**Snippet**

```js
function hashthis(str) {
  return `Hash(${str})`;
}

class Person {
  constructor(name, hash = hashthis(name)) {
    this.hash = hash;
    this.name = name;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.name + " hashValue: " + this.hash;
  }
}

console.log(new Person('Ele'));
console.log(new Person('Ele', 'dhgf65df6df7'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do if you want, is to differentiate the process of create a person the first time and the process of recover a person already created.

For example:

```js
function yourHashFunction(text) {
 //your hash function code
}

class Person {
    constructor(name, hash) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hash = hash ? hash : yourHashFunction(name);
    }

    static fromDatabase(name, hash) {
        return new Person(name, hash);
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name + " hashValue: " + this.hash;
    }
}

const pers1 = new Person('Gijs'); // user adds new Person

const pers2 = Person.fromDatabase('Gijs', '2f23f67'); // Person from database
```

Using the static function fromDatabase(or the name you prefer) helps you to identify the places(maybe you could need in some scenario, or maybe you even need for track purposes) where you create persons the first time, and when you recover persons already created.